# Spark SQL - Create UDF for casting to dynamic datatype

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a select query in which I cast string or double value to decimal as shown below:

```
Select
  CAST(Salary as Decimal(10,2)) as Salary,
  CAST(Amount as Decimal(5,2)) as Amount,
  CAST(Loan as Decimal(5,3)) as Loan
From
  Employees
```

I want to move this CAST in a user defined function and call that user define function something like this:

```
Select
  custom_cast(Salary, Decimal(10,2)) as Salary,
  custom_cast(Amount, Decimal(5,2)) as Amount,
  custom_cast(Loan, Decimal(5,3)) as Loan
From
  Employees
```

And SQL function like

```
function custom_cast(col string, datatype string) {
  return cast(col as datatype)
}
```

How can I achieve this ? I am new to spark.

Comment: why do you want to do this ?

Comment: above code is just an example. I have around 50 columns for which some check needs to be performed before casting. so thought its better to create a common function rather than writing same line again and again.

Comment: you want this in sql .. since you are using databricks you can do this easily using scala or python.

Comment: @ConfusedDeveloper - although you can create this in scala code, spark requires that any udf (or lambda usage) always returns the same type when invoked.  That type _can_ change for a different column but it must be fixed at time of creation.  Your options are udf, write using column api/dsl or [lambdas](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/advanced/userFunctions/).  However per s.polam - please give some examples of what you are trying to actually achieve and have tried